# How to slug update if I update entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, stofdoctrineextensions

My ask - if I create user, in my field slug set - firstname+lastname. if I update fields firstname and lastname slug not change, why?And What me need to do for this trable check? Because I use slug field(username) in my routing
I have:

```
class SUser implements UserInterface
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"firstName", "lastName"}, separator="-")
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 * @Assert\Length(min=3, max=255)
 */
protected $username;
```

my form:

```
class DeveloperPersonalInformationType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array                $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('firstname', null, array('label' => 'First Name', 'max_length' => 255, 'required' => false))
        ->add('lastname', null, array('label' => 'Last Name', 'max_length' => 255, 'required' => false))
```

Now I use custom variant, first get firstname and lastname end set in username, but I want use @Gedmo\Slug, how to do it? My action:

```
    public function submitPersonalInformationAction($username)
    {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $request = $this->get('request');
    $profileRepository = $this->get('artel.profile.developer.repository');
    $developer = $profileRepository->findOneByUsername($username);


    $form = $this->createForm(new DeveloperPersonalInformationType(), $developer);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) 
    {
        $name = $developer->getFirstName().'-'.$developer->getLastName();
        $developer->setUsername($name);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('artel_profile_homepage', array('username' => $name)) .'#personal-information');
    }
```

And my roting:

```
artel_profile_submit_personal_information:
path:     /profile/{username}/personal_information/submit
defaults: { _controller: ArtelProfileBundle:DeveloperProfile:submitPersonalInformation }
requirements: { _method: post }
```

my config:

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
default_locale: "%locale%"
orm:
    default:
        timestampable: true
        sluggable:     true
```

Comment: Its normal but and if you update fields in data base you slug change?

Answer (score 0):

you have set the slug field to Null for it to update

https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sluggable.md#regenerating-slug

Comment: I am not understand, I add in my action, in front if form->isValid
`$developer->setUsername(null);
        $em->flush();`
and now I have in slig field null. Where need put post this code
`$developer->setUsername(null);
        $em->flush();`
??

Comment: I use this:        
`if ($form->isValid()) {
            $name = $developer->getFirstName().'-'.$developer->getLastName();
            $developer->setUsername($name);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('artel_profile_homepage', array('username' => $name)) .'#personal-information');
        }`
and this code work, but I want use @Gedmo\Slug

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

```
if ($form->isValid()) 
{
    $developer->setUsername(Null);
    $em->flush($developer);

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('artel_profile_homepage', array('username' => $name)) .'#personal-information');
}
```

But I've note tested it.

Comment: I tested, field 'username' = null